# Does Italian citizens need a passport for a stopover in Kyiv, Ukraine?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, ukraine, stopovers, italian-citizens

I should go to Vilnius from Rome in December, and the best option is the one with a stopover in Kyiv.

I have never had a passport, as I have always traveled within EU and I could travel using my ID Card. Do I need a passport for the stopover in Kyiv?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need a passport if you have to clear immigration in Kyiv. If you fly a low cost carrier such as Ryanair, or otherwise need to change between terminals D and F at KBP, then you'll need to go through Ukraine immigration, and this requires a passport. Italian citizens do not need a visa for entering Ukraine though.

If both of your flight segments are on Ukraine International, then you should be able to transit without going through immigration in Kyiv as both of these flights use Terminal D.

The [UIA web site](https://www.flyuia.com/ir/en/information/visas-and-customs) explains that you don't need the passport if you remain in the international transit area:

> The passengers-citizens of EEA Member State, who travel from EEA member state only on UIA flights (operating carrier is PS) with the connection through Boryspil International Airport (from INTERNATIONAL to INTERNATIONAL FLIGHTS) and who do not require visa for the further travel are accepted for transportation providing that they have a valid ID card. The presentation of a passport for this category of passengers is not mandatory.

Since you are physically exiting the EU it is best to have a passport, even if you might not need it, in case of any emergency or change of plans.

Comment: Unless there is a reference to the contrary, I would consider it very high risk to go to another country without a passport, even for transit and even when a visa is not required.

Comment: You can travel from Germany to the various Schengen countries using the ID card (Personalausweis)

Comment: The answer is correct. EEA citizens can under certain conditions transit at Kiev-Boryspil with only a national ID card. https://www.flyuia.com/ir/en/information/visas-and-customs. Note that this is about Ukraine. Other countries would insist on a valid passport in a similar situation.